# Can we setup an application fullscreen and only allow the users to operate within the application?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, operating-systems, parental-controls

I am setting up an exhibit and want to display an application and my website on an iMac. I don't want the users to do anything other than looking at my website and play around the application (or even just one of those instead of doing both).

I currently use the parental control but obviously the users can still shut down my app or chrome browser. I want to prevent them from doing that. Basically I want a feature like on iOS that lock the user to an app. Can I do that in OS X even with some paid apps? Thanks.

Comment: The word you need to search for is "Kiosk". :)

Comment: I know there is a Safari Only Mode but that is not what I look for. I need the app to be full screen. If that's not what you refer to, can you provide an url? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=osx+kiosk+lockdown - First result: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97471/lock-down-osx-10-7-5-app-into-kiosk-mode

Comment: Right, xStand or eCrisper are actually just web browser and they are somewhat outdated. Additionally they both allow the users to quit them very easily.